# Is there a way to read all key-value pairs in the JSON file and then initialize all variables accordingly in shell?

Tags: json, bash, shell, variables, jq

Given a JSON file, `arguments.json`:

```
{"dagger": true, "version": false, "nether_strike": true, 
 "greater_bash": "5", "FILE": "ancientscroll.txt", 
 "empower_haste": "1", "help": false}
```

I can read using `jq` in shell and initialize the variables individually:

```
dagger=$(cat arguments.json | jq '.["dagger"]')
greater_bash =$(cat arguments.json | jq '.["greater_bash"]')    

echo $dagger
echo $greater_bash
```

**Is there a way to read all key-value pairs in the JSON file and then initialize all variables accordingly in shell?**

Comment: As an aside, `jq` (like pretty much every competently written Unix utility) accepts a file name argument, and if it didn't (like with `tr`) you'd use redirection to avoid the [useless use of `cat`](http://www.iki.fi/era/unix/award.html). `dagger=$(jq '.["dagger"]' <arguments.json)`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can loop over the key/value pairs and use `declare` to create variable names dynamically.

```
while read -r name value; do
    declare "$name=$value"
done < <(jq -r 'to_entries[] | "\(.key) \(.value)"' arguments.json)
```

Comment: Sorry for the shell noobiness, it's a little hard to read for me. Where can I input the `arguments.json`? Is it `<(cat arguments.json| jq -r 'to_entries[] | "\(.key) \(.value)"')`?

Comment: Oops, I left that out. It should be the last argument to `jq`.

Comment: What do you think about this? `source <(jq -r 'to_entries[] | "\(.key)=\"\(.value)\""' arguments.json)`

Comment: @glennjackman It's risky. Consider a contrived input like `{"foo": "bar\"baz"}`. You end up trying to execute `foo="bar"baz"`, with an unclosed quote.

Comment: I do get a `Syntax error: redirection unexpected` from Jenkins though the shell is set to `bash`. Any hints to fix that?