# How to remove the quotes when reading a variable in jq in shell?

Tags: json, bash, shell, sed, jq

Given a JSON file, `arguments.json`:

```
{"dagger": true, "version": false, "nether_strike": true, 
 "greater_bash": "5", "FILE": "ancientscroll.txt", 
 "empower_haste": "1", "help": false}
```

When calling reading the variables as such:

```
#!/bin/bash
dagger=$(cat arguments.json | jq '.["dagger"]')
greater_bash =$(cat arguments.json | jq '.["greater_bash"]')    

echo $dagger
echo $greater_bash
```

[out]:

```
true
"5"
```

The variable contains the quotation marks `""`.

**How to remove the quotes when reading a variable in jq?**

---

I could use `sed` to strip the quotes as such:

```
greater_bash =$(cat arguments.json | jq '.["greater_bash"]' | sed -e 's/^"//' -e 's/"$//')
echo $greater_bash
```

[out]:

```
5
```

**But is there a way to just strip the quotes when reading from `jq`?**

Comment: `jq -r` for raw output

Comment: As [jeberle](https://stackoverflow.com/users/867757/jeberle) indicated and as shown in the [answer to your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46187922/8379597), use `jq -r` for raw output i.e no extra quotes.  Also for some reason jq occasionally decides it wants to give me colored output when I don't want it so I always use `-M` in my scripts to ensure jq doesn't add coloring codes.  You may find it worthwhile to spend a moment reviewing the [Invoking jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#Invokingjq) section of the online manual to see if any other options make sense for you.

Comment: Thanks @jq170727 !! The link to the manual is extremely helpful!

Comment: Indeed.  I also found the [jq source](https://github.com/stedolan/jq/tree/master/src) very helpful as well, especially [builtin.jq](https://github.com/stedolan/jq/blob/master/src/builtin.jq).  There is also a lot of good information in the [jq cookbook](https://github.com/stedolan/jq/wiki/Cookbook) and on [rosettacode](https://rosettacode.org/wiki/Category:Jq)